# django tastypie performance tuning

Tags: python, django, performance, nginx, tastypie

I have a site using django-tastypie to feed data to mobile apps through API. When doing a first apache-benchmark test to our API, I noticed the performance is not as good as I expected (have to admit that I don't have a solid base to support my expectation). My server setup is as following: 2.4GHZ 2-core CPU, 2560M memory, ubuntu12.04. I use nginx with uwsgi, setting uwsgi to use 4 workers, and nginx with 4 worker_processes as well.

Here is my ab result from an API endpoint. The query is across 7 tables, with 30+ queries, and with a bunch of nested resources. When I profiled the SQL query, only 3 of them take more than 1ms (1ms, 1ms and 2ms, respectively).

```
ab -n 100 -c 8  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip'  "http://mysite"
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking lvxingjia.cc (be patient).....done


Server Software:        nginx/1.4.1
Server Hostname:        mysite
Server Port:            80

Document Path:          mysite
Document Length:        10807 bytes

Concurrency Level:      8
Time taken for tests:   19.146 seconds
Complete requests:      100
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      1117500 bytes
HTML transferred:       1080700 bytes
Requests per second:    5.22 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       1531.720 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       191.465 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          57.00 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:       16   37  56.5     23     485
Processing:   775 1455 238.1   1502    1901
Waiting:      765 1443 237.8   1488    1889
Total:        794 1492 235.7   1555    1920

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1555
  66%   1626
  75%   1653
  80%   1694
  90%   1758
  95%   1783
  98%   1903
  99%   1920
 100%   1920 (longest request)
```

I'm pretty new to performance tuning and even don't want to bother doing it if it's not something terrible since we don't have too much traffic right now.

So my first question is: is the number reasonable given my server resource and complexity of the request?

My second question is if the number is unacceptable, which area should I look into to get improvement? DB queries, line-profiling django? I got the line-profiling result, actually see a tastypie issue with deepcopy, which had also been reported by other users, and the monky-patch does improve my performance by about 30%.

I also see a great post here: [Bad Django / uwsgi performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14962289/bad-django-uwsgi-performance), but I expect some opinion about my situation given my server/request scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Where gzip compression is done? In nginx or django? What are gzip compression settings?

Comment: gzip is done in nginx. I set gzip_http_version to 1.0 so that ab requests can get gzipped json data. I can verify through document_length that gzip is working. But actually it doesn't change performance that much, since the bottleneck isn't in bandwidth I think.

Comment: Actually I asked because it's pretty usual when somebody set `gzip_comp_level` bigger than 1 and as a result performance suffers.

Comment: If you are accessing an endpoint that returns lists of elements, consider caching the response, or otherwise speeding up serialization as tastypie might hiccup on long lists of data serialization (even though db query is blazing fast).

Comment: @kroolik: isn't caching against the purpose of load-tesing? Do you have any example about speeding up serialization or an example of what condition may cause the slowness?

Comment: @Z.Lin, the purpose of load-testing is to check how many requests you can handle per second. The way you achieve it, is irrelevent as long as you acomplish goals you want. Caching is actually one of the ways to improve performance, but it can lead to temporary data inconsistency (it can, but doesn't have to - depending on how you do it). If you agree to temporary data inconsistence between requests (i.e. data being off for few seconds), then you can actually gain A LOT of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you accessing the exact same query url 100 times?  If so, caching would do wonders.

You're seeing poor perf because all the requests are queued up and processed sequentially.  Being able to process your requests concurrently would help.  You'd need more CPU cores to handle your web requests.

Moving your SQL server to another machine might help as well.

Comment: caching is an inherent part of computing performance, from your L1 CPU cache up to memcache/redis/varnish etc.  And by caching, I don't necessarily mean the final HTML/json your API may be delivering.  Caching the intermediate database requests would give you a performance boost too.

Comment: Just in terms of general direction, tastypie often goes overboard with queries on nested resources, since they'll go through the nesting and pull up all sorts of stuff.  You can either minimize this, or maximize caching to improve perf.  This would be the first place I'd start digging.